# Updating partial view from another partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, multi-select

I have two partial views, one is multi select list of categories, other one is all products from selected categories, also multi select list.

I want to update second partial view on selected category or on a button click. I am not able to find any example like this, so if anyone have any idea how to do this it would be great

Answer (score 1):

From the client-side you use an ajax call to with a parameter about the selected category in your first partial view. Then server-side the call returns the second partial view rendered with the right products base on the category parameter that was sent.

Example of an ajax call (with jQuery):

```
function GetProducts(categoryID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Controller/GetProducts',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ categoryID: categoryID }),
        dataType: 'html',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) { OnGetProductsPartialViewCallback(data); },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { OnGetProductsPartialViewError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown); }
    });
}

function OnGetProductsPartialViewCallback(data) {
  $('#div-products').html(data);
  ...
}

function OnGetProductsPartialViewError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  ...
}
```

Server-side code:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult GetProducts(int categoryID)
{
    try
    {
        var products = // get products
        return PartialView("Products", new ProductsViewModel(products));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Products could not be loaded.", ex);
    }
}
```

Hope this points you in the right direction ;)